# maximum and minimum finding in c# listbox

Tags: c#

```
private void tbimput_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyChar==(char)13)
    {
        if(tbimput.Text!="")
        {
            lbprices.Items.Add(tbunos.Text);
            tbprices.Text="";
        }
    }
}

private void btracunaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i,n,l,j;
    double x,y,max,min;
    n = lbprices.Items.Count;
    l = lbprices.Items.Count;
    x = Convert.ToDouble(lbprices.Items[0]);
    y = Convert.ToDouble(lbprices.Items[0]);
    max = n;

    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        x=Convert.ToDouble(lbprices.Items[i]);

        if (x > max)
        {
            max = x;
        }                
    }

    min = l;

    for(j=1;j<l;j++)
    {
        y = Convert.ToDouble(lbprices.Items[j]);

        if (y < min)
        {
            min = y;
        }
    }

        tbmax.Text = Convert.ToString(max);
        tbmin.Text = Convert.ToString(min);
    }
}
```

How is it possible to find the maximum and minimum values in a ListBox using cycle counting. I tried but it doesn't give me the minimum, only the maximum.For the minimum it gives me just a number of prices in ListBox. I have been trying for a very long time but have not been able to succeed.

Comment: you're missing brackets `{}` around your second for loop

Comment: i put them now it is not that it still do same

Comment: You should update your code in the question so that it is clear to other potential answerers that you are still having the problem

Comment: Also, instead of setting `max = n` and `min = l`, which are just synonyms for `lbprices.Items.Count`, it would make more sense to set `max = 0` and `min = Int32.MaxValue`

Comment: With this code, if `lbprices.Items.Count` is less than the minimum item in the list, you're going to get `lbprices.items.Count` instead of the actual minimum

Comment: Have you tried using linq to create a list ordered by the value you want then just get the first and last entry?

Comment: Why in the world do you user both n and l for the same thing - count.  Why do you assign min a max to the count?

Answer (score 1):

One pass is going to be the most efficient

```
double max = Convert.ToDouble(lbprices.Items[0]);
double min = max;

for(i = 1; i < lbprices.Items.count; i++)
{
    x = Convert.ToDouble(lbprices.Items[i]);
    if      (x > max)
        max = x;    
    else if (x < min)
        min = x;          
}
```

Comment: In your function min and max are the same? Also what about the first entry in Items[]? You start at 1 skipping the first (index of 0) entry in your for loop.

Comment: @CalebB did you down vote me?  > is not the same as <.  And the values are assigned Items[0] to start with.   Buy a vowel.

Comment: I did. I realize this, my down vote had more to do with how you were doing it than the outcome. I admit my down vote may have been premature but I am unable to undo my vote unless an edit is made.

Comment: It was a misunderstanding on my part when reading your source. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
 for(j=1;j<l;j++)
     y = Convert.ToDouble(lbprices.Items[j]);
 if (y < min)
     min = y;
```

Should be:

```
min = max;
for(j=1;j<l;j++)
{
     y = Convert.ToDouble(lbprices.Items[j]);
     if (y < min)
        min = y;
}
```

PS.
You should pay careful attention to indentation to make your code readable. It will help you avoid errors like this.

Comment: i did this now it still stil do same

Comment: Sorry, I updated my code, try it now... notice the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of strings - or any `IEnumerable<string>` type:

```
var x = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3","7389" };
```

Minimum: `var min = x.Min(y => Int32.Parse(y));`

Maximum: `var max = x.Max(y => Int32.Parse(y)))`

If you don't have a `IEnumerable<string>` but the type is castable to string, you can first `var z = x.Cast<string>();` and then perform the operation on the new list.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use your loops more or less the way you have them now, you should do:

```
max = Int32.MinValue;

for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    x=Convert.ToDouble(lbprices.Items[i]);

    if (x > max)
    {
        max = x;
    }                
}

min = Int32.MaxValue;

for(j=1;j<l;j++)
{
    y = Convert.ToDouble(lbprices.Items[j]);

    if (y < min)
    {
        min = y;
    }
}
```

If you want to do something cleaner with Linq, you could do:

```
var orderedItems = lbprices.Items.Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x)).OrderBy(x => x);

var min = orderedItems.First();
var max = orderedItems.Last();
```

Or, even cleaner, @Andrej's use of .Min() and .Max():

```
var items = lbprices.Items.Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x));

var min = items.Min();
var max = items.Max();
```